# PyGTK - "Could not show link" in AboutDialog

Tags: gtk, pygtk

My `GtkAboutDialog` has its `website` attribute set to a valid URL.
When clicking on it, the window freezes, and then I get the following warning:

```
Could not show link
HEAD request failed: WinHttp error: TIMEOUT
```

Just to clarify, in other point of my program I explicitly access a website with `webbrowser.open`, and it easily opens the URL in the browser.

## EDIT

After investigation, it appears that the `website` feature is using `gtk.show_uri()`. Calling it from the Python console (like this: `gtk.show_uri(None, "http://www.google.com", gtk.gdk.CURRENT_TIME)` ).

I have bypassed the problem by re-assigning the `uri_hook` to my custom function.

```
def uri_hook_func(self, ignore1, url, ignore2):
    webbrowser.open(url, new=2)
...
    gtk.about_dialog_set_url_hook(self.uri_hook_func, data=None)
```

Comment: This is because `gvfs` is missing which is required by `gtk.show_uri`. You solved your and my problem. Could you possibly post your update as an answer?